# Infinite monkey theorem and numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I had a discussion with a friend about the monkey infinite theorem, the theorem says that a monkey typing randomly on a keyboard will almost surely produce any given books (here let's say the bible).

I believe this experience can be reduced to choosing a random sequence among real numbers:, strictly speaking the monkey could type a sequence looking like 1/3. (Characters replaced by numbers), my friend told that it is not possible, but for me this is what pure randomness is.

I also believe that not all infinite sequences contain the bible, so it doesn't make any sense to say that the monkey will almost surely write it.

My friend is sure that the monkey will ALWAYS write everything possible, while for me this implies to always choose a "disjunctive sequence".

I understand that from a probabilistic point of view, the chance that the monkey doesn't write a particular sequence drop to 0 as the number of character increase. But probability is also the ratio of specific events on all the events, since all the sequences are not disjunctive sequence, this probability cannot be equal to 1.

Who is right here?

Comment: There are some things that have zero probability that can occur. If you pick a random number in $[0,1]$ the probability of you picking that number is zero and yet you just picked it

Comment: Then what, it means that the monkey cannot write a sequence without a particular book? isn't it a bias to assume that?

Comment: @aldodecristo - Can you prove that you just picked a *random* number?

Comment: The confusion arises between the idea of something never occurring and it having zero probability. In your cases the probability that the monkeys write a book is certain (has probability $1$) while the probability that they all hit the same key forever has probability $0$.

Comment: It is worth emphasizing what is meant by "random" here as well... random in this context is that each key pressed by the monkey is *uniformly selected at random (and so in particular every keypress is possible with positive probability)* and each keypress's result is *independent* of each other.  Now, you talk about "*probability is the ratio of specific events on all the events*"... that is incorrect.  That interpretation of probability is only accurate when talking about finite sample spaces where each outcome is equally likely to occur.  It fails for infinite sample spaces.

Comment: Now... if you were to just look at the first page of what the monkey has written, [it is often going to be garbage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loMEF18Ir4s).

Comment: @JMoravitz Do you have reference about infinite sample spaces? The probability that the monkey doesn't write a given book is non-zero, do we agree about that?

Comment: Infinity is *really big*... An infinitely long sequence of characters that monkeys might randomly type is *really long*...  "*The probability that the monkey doesn't write a given book is non-zero, do we agree about that?*"  No, we don't agree.  An infinitely long sequence of characters, each character independently and uniformly selected at random will contain a particular given subsequence with probability $1$ and will not contain said particular given subsequence with probability zero.  "*Probability zero*" here is in reference to being smaller than any positive real value.

Comment: Again... do not confuse the phrase "*impossible*" which means that the outcome is not in the sample space at all with the phrase "*occurs with probability zero*" which merely means that the probability the outcome occurs is less than any given positive real number but might still allow for the outcome to be in the sample space.  Also, do not confuse the problem of looking at the first page that the monkey writes with the problem of looking at the entire collection of infinitely many pages that the monkey writes.  See [Almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely).

Comment: As for "*do you have a reference about infinite sample spaces?*"  Literally every introductory probability textbook should cover this in plenty of detail.

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, what you say here is that, given an infinite amount of time, everything that is plausible, will happen certainly (and it will happen an infinite amount of time) which doesn't seem right to me. I am more curious about the infinite sequences that don't contain the given book (They exist right?) It means that the monkey cannot write them?

Comment: They exist, yes, however they are *so improbable* to exist that they "*Almost never*" appear and occur with probability less than any choice of a positive real number, thus receiving the designation of having "Probability zero."  Whether it seems right to you or not, that is something you will have to grow past.  You must understand the meanings of the words "Almost surely" and "Almost never" and you must throw away any preconceived notions and misconceptions about how what works for finite cases when trying to think about what happens in infinite cases.

Comment: The monkey *can write them* however is *so unlikely* to write them that it *almost never* happens.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have no problem with the terms, the theorem and I FULLY understand the concept, but this little detail is annoying, and I thought it might be interesting to look for (it isn't believing you). This basically means that disjunctive sequences are so common in R, that when you pick a number randomly you are almost certain to pick one.

Comment: "When you pick a number randomly" *from the unit interval*. You can't uniformly at random pick a real number from the entire continuum, just from finite intervals. And yes, this does imply the measure of the disjunctive numbers is 1 and the measure of the set of numbers which aren't is zero... that is a straight rewording of the infinite monkey theorem.  Again, measure zero does not mean "is empty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 examples you made (the bible and the sequence of the number $\frac{1}{3}$) are similar, but deeply different. In fact, the bible is a *finite* sequence of characters, whereas the decimal digits of $\frac{1}{3}$ are infinitely many.

So, the probability that the monkey writes exactly the bible during its typing is 1, while the probability that the monkey will write exactly *all* the digits of $\frac{1}{3}$ is 0.

**Digits of $\frac{1}{3}$**

In order to write exactly the digits of $\frac{1}{3}$, from a certain digits the monkey must push the key 0 and then the key 3 infinitely many times... up to infinity! This has probability (not rigorous) $\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10} * \dots * \frac{1}{10} = (\frac{1}{10})^\infty = 0$.

**Sequence of letters of the bible**

In order to write exactly the sequence of letters of the bible, instead, the monkey should guess a finite number of characters.

The first thing we can notice is that the probability that this happens is larger than 0. In fact, assuming that the bible is 1.000.000 letters long, the probability that the bible starts from the *first letter of the first page* that the monkey writes is something like $p = \frac{1}{26} * \frac{1}{26} * \dots * \frac{1}{26} = (\frac{1}{26})^{1.000.000}$, which is a very small number, but it is larger than 0.

Then, think that the bible could start from the *second letter of the first page*, so we have another $p$ probability that the monkey will write exactly the bible. And consider that the monkeys has infinitely many letters from which it can start to write the bible, so it has infinitely many chances to succeed in the challenge, each of them having $p$ probability to work.

Note that these infinitely many events (each corresponding to which letter the monkey is starting to write the bible from) are not independent, so the total probability will not be $\infty * p = \infty$, but they are enough to guarantee that the monkey will achieve it anyway, with probability 1.

The rigorous proof that this probability is 1 is not even difficult, but I will not write it here. You can find it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).

The idea of the proof is to estimate the probability that *the monkey will not write the bible* and eventually you can proof that that probability is 0, meaning that it is almost impossible (but still not impossible) that the monkey doesn't write the bible.

Comment: This is an excellent answer (+1) except for the very last half sentence. 'meaning that it **cannot** happen that the monkey doesn't write the bible' (emphasis mine) is wrong: it is very easy to imagine what this would look like (the monkey typing 1/3 just being one example) so it certainly **can** happen. But in spite of it being possible the event of not typing the bible still has probably 0 as you explain. It might well be that most of the confusion the OP is having stems from the fact that having probability zero and being impossible are *not* equivalent.

Comment: Of course, an event that is truly impossible will have probability zero, but conversely having probability zero does not mean impossible, it 'merely' means that the probability of it happening can be shown to be smaller than any given positive real number. If we keep on insisting that this probability is nevertheless *some* real number in [0,1] (which we of course insist, since it is in the definition of probability) then 0 remains as the only remaining option for its value.

Comment: You are right, I know the difference and I should write that sentence better. I will edit it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, to be honest my question have already been answered in the comments, I was bothered by a little detail that @Vincent summarized. The comments below the question made me understand why this little detail is still compatible with the theorem.